# Can users pickle and then reload all variables in one shot? Idea for an AutoSave function

Tags: python

I want to save all the global variables into a pickle file, and then reload the pickle file and have it retrieve all the pickled values and put them back into their original variables.  This will be the basis for auto save function of a databasing program that I'm writing, so that if you want to end off that logging session, the script will auto save the entire environment variables, so that you can easily reload it later and continue with everything being as it was before you saved.

I can't figure out though how to do this.  This code below works, but if you look at the second print of variables once it is done, the globals (ab&c) are still zeroed out, instead of being refilled from the pickle.

Is it even possible to reassign all the globals in one shot?  What am I missing?

```
import pickle

global a,b,c

a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

print (globals())

AutoPickleFile = open('z:\\Pickle.txt','wb')
pickle.dump(globals, AutoPickleFile)
AutoPickleFile.close()

a = 0
b = 0
c = 0

AutoPickleFile = open('z:\\Pickle.txt','rb')
globals = pickle.load(AutoPickleFile)
AutoPickleFile.close()

print (globals())
```

Comment: `globals` is a *function*, it returns a reference to the current globals dictionary. It is not, itself, the globals mapping.

Comment: The `global` keyword on line 3 does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this is a bad idea.

`globals()` contains much more than just `a`, `b` and `c`; the `pickle` module is *also* a global in your module. Moreover, the `globals()` mapping also holds a reference to the `__builtins__` object, where all the Python built-ins live, including the `globals()` function itself. You don't need to pickle any of these.

Stick to pickling just what you need to persist:

```
 with open('z:\\Pickle.txt', 'wb') as AutoPickleFile:
     pickle.dump((a, b, c), AutoPickleFile)
```

and load again with:

```
 with open('z:\\Pickle.txt', 'rb') as AutoPickleFile:
     a, b, c = pickle.load(AutoPickleFile)
```

You tried to treat `globals`, the built-in function, as a reference to the dictionary; you'd have to *call* the function to get access to the mapping for pickling instead.

Answer (score 2):

It would be far better to have a "namespace" that you serialize with JSON or another data format. Then it would be far far far cleaner to load and de-load...

e.g..

```
vars = {}
vars["a"] = 444
a = open("test.json", "w")
a.write(json.dumps(vars))
a.close()
vars = json.loads(open("test.json"))
```

Pickle is unreliable and very python specific, doing it in a better format is far better in the long run.